# border внутри текста

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли сделать обводку в внутри текста на css ,вот пример:
[image: border внутри текста]

Comment: проще сделать пунктир и обводку вокруг него )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обводу чего? Тень? Если вы про пунктир, то насколько мне известно то нет, а если и можно, то поддерживается в 1-2 браузере, и в любом случае лучше воспользоваться картинкой. Но на всякий случай скажу: есть вот такой [трюк](http://jsfiddle.net/igolka97/ughov04u/) с тенью.

З.Ы. Если очень сильно надо что бы этот текст был динамическим, и с такой обводкой, и вам <strike>заплатят много денег</strike> нечего делать, то попробуйте генерировать эти картинки динамически, с помощью `php` и таких библиотек как `gd` или `Imagick`

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду пунктир.

Comment: @Mr_Epic Дописал ответ

Comment: @igolka97: У вас же вроде был профиль на Хэшкоде? Он импортировался сюда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2138/igolka97

Comment: Можно еще шрифт такой векторно создать и его внедрить через `@font-face`.

Comment: @VladD А, все, восстановил